# What is the right approach to create an admin panel , that can create users and apply roles in a React JS app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend

Currently im working on a project that I need an admin panel (login). This admin should create other users  and apply a role to this users. So then the user, depending on the role should log in and have access to differents forms. The admin user have to create users, apply a role and reset the password if necesary.
Thanks in advance.

I was thinking Auth0 or Firebase, but none of them give me the posibility that an admin, create and assign a role to the user, plus it asked user for an email. Which is not necessary, i just need User and password.

Answer (score 1):

I think an interesting solution for you would be [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/). It is a free and oopen source auth manager. Obviously, it is a little bit harder than the paid options and needs a considerable ammount of configuration before you can actually run it, but gives you more freedom on how to do stuff, for example, you don't need the users to give you an e-mail to create their accounts.

Also, if you are only interested on an admin page to control the users of your app, Keycloak has it already developed. If you are looking only for the auth system and wants to build an admin console by yourself, you can control it via HTTP requests (that are some npm packages that help you deal with this, although they are not official).

However, if you only want to build the app fast then I would probably try to find some other solution, as Keycloak might be a little bit tough on the start.